# Eclipseでマルチプロジェクトの作成方法がわからない

Tags: android, java, eclipse, gradle, maven

EclipseでAndroidアプリケーションを作りたいです。
サーバ側もJava + Springで作成する予定です。

Androidとサーバの間はJSONを使って通信を行いたいので、プロジェクトを3つに分けられないかなと考えています。

1. Androidプロジェクト
2. サーバサイドプロジェクト
3. Json通信を行う際にデータを入れるPOJOのプロジェクト(1/2から共通で参照)

Eclipseを1つしか立ち上げないで開発すると大変そうなので、1/2は別のワークスペースにしてEclipseを2つ立ち上げて開発したいなと思います。

このような感じで開発したいのですが、Eclipseでどうやればマルチプロジェクトにできるかよくわからないんです。

Eclipseでプロジェクトを作ると、Androidはただのプロジェクトに、サーバ側(Sprint Tool Suiteを使って作成したプロジェクト)はMavenプロジェクトになっちゃいます。

普通に考えればMaven or Gradleのどちらで統一した方がいいと思うんです。
だけれども、Maven/Gradleのどっちもよくわかりません。

すいませんが、Eclipseを使ってマルチプロジェクト構成にする方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

１つのワークスペースに
３つプロジェクトをいれる　ではダメなんでしたっけ。。。？

Answer (score 1):

ワークスペースと、プロジェクトの関係であいまいのまま作業されているように思えますが…、
マルチプロジェクト（？）にしたい意図は何でしょうか。

- 1つのワークスペースに3つのプロジェクトが並んでいる状態で何か問題ありますでしょうか。
- 1つのプロジェクトから他のプロジェクト参照はビルドパスの設定で可能です。
- mavenを使うのであれば、mavenのプロジェクトとして他プロジェクトを参照できます。

なお、複数のプロジェクトを束ねるものとしてマルチ"モジュール"プロジェクトの形式がありますが、その前にmaven/gradleを使ったプロジェクトの構成について学習すべきと存じます。